# Delete users with no posts in WordPress using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a SQL script to delete users with no posts associated with them in a WordPress database. I tried this script after doing some searching:

```
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM wp_105_posts)
```

but this deleted all the users. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like either none of the users made posts, or `wp_105_posts.post_author` doesn't link to `wp_users.ID`. Are you sure `wp_105_posts.post_author` is a Foreign Key of `wp_users.ID`?

`wp_105_posts` should have *one* column that references *who* the user is in the `wp_users` table. Since your GUID Primary Key for `wp_users` is `ID`, this should be the one column you use to reference the user from your post tables. Here is a small example:

**user_table**
**ID | name | age |     email     | etc.**
1  | nick | 24  | nick@com.com  | ..
2  | bob  | 30  | bob@com.com   | ...
3  | sue  | 35  | sue@com.com   | ...

**a_post_table**
**ID (ID of post) | User_ID (ID of user) | title | date | body**
........1..............|...1 (post by nick)........ | help | 1/1/11
........2..............|...1 (post by nick)........ | help | 3/2/11
........3..............|...2 (post by bob)........ | help | 5/6/11

As you can see, the post table knows everything about the author by simply holding its ID. You can use a join query to get all user info from the post table just by knowing its ID. Using this query now

```
DELETE FROM user_table
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT User_ID FROM a_post_table)
```

Will delete Sue, and Sue only, given the data above.
HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response Shredder. The primary keys for my wp_users tables are: PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename` and the primary keys for my wp_105_posts table are: PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`) - Should I be using one of these? Apologies, I am a beginner.

Comment: I have revised my script 
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM wp_136_posts, wp_137_posts, wp_138_posts, wp_139_posts, wp_140_posts, wp_141_posts) but now I get the following error Error code: 1052 Column ‘post_author’ in field list is ambiguous. Can anyone help with this?